# How to apply error-correction to the swap test circuit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, error-correction, swap-test

Swap test is a simple quantum circuit to measure the inner product of two quantum states [[Wiki: swap test]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test), it only contains three quantum gates. However, due to the error in the real quantum computer (gate error, measurement error, decoherence, etc), the swap test can not be perfectly implemented.

[image]

How to design a quantum circuit that applies the quantum-error-correction method to handle the errors? Is it possible to handle arbitrary errors?

Answer (score 1):

> How to design a quantum circuit that applies the quantum-error-correction method to handle the errors?

Each qubit in the circuit has to be encoded in a quantum error correction code. You need to choose a quantum error correction code for which you know how to fault-tolerantly implement a universal logical gate set. Then you have to decompose the controlled swap into this logical gate set.

> Is it possible to handle arbitrary errors?

Yes, fault-tolerant quantum computing is possible.

Comment: There is a subtlety here. If $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are provided as single qubit states, then one way is to start by encoding them into $n$-qubit encoded states. But that process of encoding itself will have errors that can destroy the states. A better way would be to teleport the one-qubit input states onto pre-prepared $n$-qubit encoded zero states. The core idea being to aggressively minimize the number of identity or non-identity gates being applies to your input states.